# how to get records from table with uniq on two columns - rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to fetch records from database that should be uniqued by two attributes 
example

> id   name   value
>
> 1    dog     4
>
> 2    dog     4
>
> 3    cat     5
>
> 4    cat     4

I want the result to be

> id   name   value
>
> 1    dog     4
>
> 3    cat     5
>
> 4    cat     4

so the data has been uniqued by value and name , I've tried many ways with  ruby  to do but with no luck

Comment: Do you really want the ID? That is an odd requirement for this. You can do min/max as answered below, but that is not usually a good idea unless there is a specific business need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with group  method of rails

```
table.all.group('value, name')
```

the generated query is

```
select * from table t group by value, name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`:

```
select min(id) as id, name, value
from table t
group by name, value;
```